# Centering Two Elements Together In Tandem with HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to achieve this with two elements:

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 2]

The point is that if one div is smaller than the other div, it moves in such a way that its y-center is the same at the other div's y-center.

But I couldn't find anything that would let me do this with CSS. Any suggestions?

I'm using Bootstrap, and using divs with columns and rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `Flexbox`. Here is [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/529/) with Bootstrap

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa doloribus mollitia reprehenderit, dignissimos temporibus. Quis sapiente nisi nemo earum, id fugit magnam eaque voluptas autem quos, nostrum, error. Voluptatibus, consequatur!</div>
  <div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You beat me to it ;-)

Comment: @Aziz sorry about that `:)`